# Heroku error with controllers Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite

Heroku logs.
When i opened my db in heidi I don't have data.
I trying to do heroku db:migrate lalaala, nothing help.

```
2016-11-04T09:07:16.038403+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mysterious-harbor-22464.herokuapp.com request_id=c24ec075-dab5-4e41-b3ea-2ecc1a77e281 fwd="93.116.117.194" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=74ms status=404 bytes=1829
2016-11-04T09:07:15.970326+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 93.116.117.194 at 2016-11-04 09:07:15 +0000
2016-11-04T09:07:16.020369+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2016-11-04T09:07:16.029704+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 404 Not Found in 9ms
2016-11-04T09:07:16.034213+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-04T09:07:16.034215+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Plan with 'id'=1):
2016-11-04T09:07:16.034216+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:3:in `home'
2016-11-04T09:07:16.034216+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-04T09:07:16.034217+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-04T09:07:24.790355+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/products" host=mysterious-harbor-22464.herokuapp.com request_id=e8c2944c-aac8-4255-a7a5-46baf6f4bac0 fwd="93.116.117.194" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=60ms status=404 bytes=1829
2016-11-04T09:07:24.734996+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/products" for 93.116.117.194 at 2016-11-04 09:07:24 +0000
2016-11-04T09:07:24.740508+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
2016-11-04T09:07:24.772436+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 404 Not Found in 32ms
2016-11-04T09:07:24.783327+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-04T09:07:24.783329+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=3):
2016-11-04T09:07:24.783331+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-04T09:07:24.783330+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/products_controller.rb:12:in `index'
2016-11-04T09:07:24.783331+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-04T09:07:28.564684+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/products/new" host=mysterious-harbor-22464.herokuapp.com request_id=c7d08df4-d09f-402b-b6f8-c47c69657c16 fwd="93.116.117.194" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=26ms status=404 bytes=1829
2016-11-04T09:07:28.543652+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/products/new" for 93.116.117.194 at 2016-11-04 09:07:28 +0000
2016-11-04T09:07:28.548321+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ProductsController#new as HTML
2016-11-04T09:07:28.558331+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 404 Not Found in 10ms
2016-11-04T09:07:28.560681+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-04T09:07:28.560683+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=3):
2016-11-04T09:07:28.560684+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/products_controller.rb:34:in `new'
2016-11-04T09:07:28.560684+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-04T09:07:28.560685+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-04T09:41:09.782908+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2016-11-04T09:41:09.783495+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2016-11-04T09:41:12.388209+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-11-04T09:41:12.738903+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-11-04 09:41:12] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2016-11-04T09:41:12.738925+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:174:in `select'
2016-11-04T09:41:12.738930+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:174:in `block in start'
2016-11-04T09:41:12.738931+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2016-11-04T09:41:12.738932+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
2016-11-04T09:41:12.738933+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2016-11-04T09:41:12.738934+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2016-11-04T09:41:12.738934+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2016-11-04T09:41:12.738935+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2016-11-04T09:41:12.738932+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2016-11-04T09:41:12.738937+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2016-11-04T09:41:12.738936+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2016-11-04T09:41:12.738937+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-11-04T09:41:12.738938+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `require'
2016-11-04T09:41:12.738939+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2016-11-04T09:41:12.738985+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-11-04 09:41:12] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2016-11-04T09:41:12.739033+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-11-04 09:41:12] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2016-11-04T09:41:12.739060+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2016-11-04T09:41:13.019823+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2016-11-04T19:44:35.838068+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 1b03d2a by gomacroice@gmail.com
2016-11-04T19:44:35.838166+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v30 created by gomacroice@gmail.com
2016-11-04T19:44:36.158956+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2016-11-04T19:44:36.219145+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-11-04T19:44:36.219153+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-11-04T19:44:39.148098+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 27508 -e production`
2016-11-04T19:44:41.106952+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:285: warning: circular argument reference - now
2016-11-04T19:44:42.517126+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-11-04 19:44:42] INFO  ruby 2.2.4 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]
2016-11-04T19:44:42.517492+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-11-04 19:44:42] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=27508
2016-11-04T19:44:42.517111+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-11-04 19:44:42] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2016-11-04T19:44:43.090664+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-11-04T19:45:07.206043+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mysterious-harbor-22464.herokuapp.com request_id=17f0024d-098e-4168-bc06-ae33b7ad206f fwd="109.185.120.41" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=99ms status=404 bytes=1829
2016-11-04T19:45:07.086186+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2016-11-04T19:45:07.086198+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:27508
2016-11-04T19:45:07.086199+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2016-11-04T19:45:07.086200+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2016-11-04T19:45:07.086200+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2016-11-04T19:45:07.086201+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 109.185.120.41 at 2016-11-04 19:45:07 +0000
2016-11-04T19:45:07.174573+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 404 Not Found in 18ms
2016-11-04T19:45:07.156086+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2016-11-04T19:45:07.175983+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Plan with 'id'=1):
2016-11-04T19:45:07.175982+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-04T19:45:07.175984+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:3:in `home'
2016-11-04T19:45:07.175984+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-04T19:45:07.175985+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-04T19:45:07.802920+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mysterious-harbor-22464.herokuapp.com request_id=4a5e3335-f8e9-4bee-ad5e-6cbe984750d2 fwd="109.185.120.41" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=228
2016-11-04T19:56:25.123706+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` by gomacroice@gmail.com
2016-11-04T19:56:28.551715+00:00 heroku[run.9872]: Awaiting client
2016-11-04T19:56:28.584068+00:00 heroku[run.9872]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
2016-11-04T19:56:28.860508+00:00 heroku[run.9872]: State changed from starting to up
2016-11-04T19:56:33.081684+00:00 heroku[run.9872]: Process exited with status 0
2016-11-04T19:56:33.078485+00:00 heroku[run.9872]: State changed from up to complete
2016-11-04T19:56:44.878320+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mysterious-harbor-22464.herokuapp.com request_id=19341742-d312-45a0-b9fd-b3a4094f847b fwd="109.185.120.41" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=404 bytes=1829
2016-11-04T19:56:44.854133+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 109.185.120.41 at 2016-11-04 19:56:44 +0000
2016-11-04T19:56:44.856628+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2016-11-04T19:56:44.858663+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms
2016-11-04T19:56:44.860301+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-04T19:56:44.860303+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Plan with 'id'=1):
2016-11-04T19:56:44.860303+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:3:in `home'
2016-11-04T19:56:44.860304+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-04T19:56:44.860304+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-04T19:56:45.454411+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mysterious-harbor-22464.herokuapp.com request_id=17b8e38a-f60b-4c0c-ba79-6ccd4db05245 fwd="109.185.120.41" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=228
2016-11-04T20:00:20.764431+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mysterious-harbor-22464.herokuapp.com request_id=6b30c6ed-e74c-455a-99d8-7237181b7f57 fwd="109.185.120.41" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=45ms status=404 bytes=1829
2016-11-04T20:00:20.753310+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 109.185.120.41 at 2016-11-04 20:00:20 +0000
2016-11-04T20:00:20.755589+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2016-11-04T20:00:20.758762+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms
2016-11-04T20:00:20.763281+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-04T20:00:20.763283+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Plan with 'id'=1):
2016-11-04T20:00:20.763284+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:3:in `home'
2016-11-04T20:00:20.763285+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-04T20:00:20.763285+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-04T20:00:21.313178+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mysterious-harbor-22464.herokuapp.com request_id=22d79fbf-f47f-4724-a180-3f0381b9426a fwd="109.185.120.41" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=228
```

gemfile

```
  source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', group: [:development, :test]

#Use postgresql as the database for production
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.3'
# Use bootsrap library for styles
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.1'
#Use font awesome library
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '4.5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', ' 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', ' 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', ' 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use devise for use authentication

gem 'devise','3.4.1'

# Use stripe for handaling payments

gem 'stripe', '1.16.1'

# Use figaro to hide secret keys

gem 'figaro', '1.0.0'

# Use Rmagic for pictures

gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.15', '>= 2.15.4'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations"}
  resources :users do
    resource :profile
  end
  resources :opsystems


  resources :categories
  resources :contacts
  resources :admins
  resources :products do
   resources :comments
   resources :pdfs
  end

  get '/about' => 'pages#about'
  get '/products' => 'pages#products'
  root 'pages#home'
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Comment: Where are those user and plan `id`s coming from? Why would you expect them to exist?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I hope you'll find the site useful. In my experience, learning to use the site also helped me to grow personally as a developer. This is a great start to asking a good question. You've tried something out and included your code. But the code is quite long and could probably be reduced to a more minimal example. It would also be useful to see an example of the expected output.